# use Effect not working to bring up my product, using axios use params,

Tags: mongodb, react-hooks, parameters

This code is not working for me i am trying to pull data from my mongodb

```
const ProductScreen = ({ match }) => {
  const [product, setProduct] = useState({});
  const { id } = useParams();

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchProduct = async () => {
      const { data } = await axios.get(
        `/api/product/${encodeURIComponent(id)}`
      );

      setProduct(data);
    };

    fetchProduct();
  }, []);
};
```

pull data from server of mongo db

Comment: Line 20:6:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'id'. Either include it or remove the dependency array

Comment: Are you getting an error message or just an empty response?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible when the component first mounts, `id` is null and `useParams()` doesn't get it till the second render. So add an if statement in your useEffect to make sure the `id` is present. Also add `id` to the dependency array, so if the `id` changes, you will refetch the data for it. Otherwise, with an empty dependency array, the `useEffect` will only run on first mount.

```
const ProductScreen = ({ match }) => {
  const [product, setProduct] = useState({});
  const { id } = useParams();

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchProduct = async () => {
      const { data } = await axios.get(
        `/api/product/${encodeURIComponent(id)}`
      );
      setProduct(data);
    };
    if (id) {
       fetchProduct();
       }
  }, [id]);
};
```